# Codeigniter: Accessing session data from array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

So I have stored my session data into the session like below:

```
        $user_data = array(
          'user_id' => $user_id,
          'email' => $email,
          'logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata('login_session', $user_data);
```

In my view, I'm trying to echo the email out onto the page but no matter which way I try to access it, it will not echo out:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('email');
```

How can I access the array values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing the values in an array & then assigning that array to a variable called `login_session` but while retrieving the data you are just accessing with only key and not with `array['key']`.

So the correct syntax is:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('login_session')['email'];
```

OR

```
$log_sess=$this->session->userdata('login_session');
echo $log_sess['email'];
```

Please go through the codeigniter document as well.

Comment: Thanks! I did try ...->userdata(['login_session']['email']); but it didn't work. Also, there is nothing in the documentation detailing this! (I couldn't find it anyway) Thanks again!

Comment: You are Welcome!